# not linking with roscpp

Tags: ros, roscpp, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Getting linking errors on everything in roscpp, serialization, console, etc.  CMakelist looks correct (have read and tried all recommend postings. Can also compile other parts of the package that link with roscpp.).  The failure occurs on with this library. Type of errors are like: `undefined reference to` ros::console::initialize()'` for example.

This is the cmakelist.txt, and it references roscpp, and also catkin_LIBRARIES has the correct capitalization...everything seems as it should be.  Apologies for the formatting, used "code block" but it doesn't stick.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(imu_complementary_filter)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cmake_modules
  message_filters
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  tf
  genmsg

)

find_package(Eigen REQUIRED COMPONENTS)

catkin_package(
  DEPENDS Eigen
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES complementary_filter
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_filters roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs tf 
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(complementary_filter
  src/complementary_filter.cpp
  src/complementary_filter_ros.cpp
  include/imu_complementary_filter/complementary_filter.h
  include/imu_complementary_filter/complementary_filter_ros.h
)

add_executable(complementary_filter_node
  src/complementary_filter_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(complementary_filter_node complementary_filter ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Eigen_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS complementary_filter complementary_filter_node
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)


install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227923/not-linking-with-roscpp/) by [codenotes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20029/codenotes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 261 on 2016-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your question "not linking with roscpp" is already the answer. Your posted CMake code does not link the library against `roscpp`. You need to call `target_link_libraries(complementary_filter ${catkin_LIBRARIES})` (and maybe also eigen).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [codenotes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20029/codenotes/) on 2016-03-01**:
there is the line:

target_link_libraries(complementary_filter_node complementary_filter ${catkin_LIBRARIES}

should that not be sufficent?  catkin_LIBRARIES includes roscpp, right?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-03-01**:
That line is for the `executable`. You need the same for the `library` if it already needs roscpp.

**Comment by [codenotes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20029/codenotes/) on 2016-03-01**:
100% correct, that solved it. the library needed its own target_link, I missed that. Although mystery as to why that was missing...this is a used public repo.  But thank you.  For reference, the package here is imu_tools:
https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools.git